# How to disable timeout in fauxton

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

In developing i use the fauxton. But it is anoying keep using the login due to timeout. Is it possible to disable the timeout login for fauxton to avoid this problem in developing? Thank you

Comment: Try increasing the [couch_httpd_auth timeout](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/timeout) value.

Comment: Got moved to `chttpd_auth`  in v3.2: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/auth.html#chttpd_auth/timeout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Fauxton
2. Go to the configuration page
3. Under `chttpd_auth` there may or may not be a `timeout` entry. If there is delete it.
4. Click "Add option". [Fill out the form where "section" is `chttpd_auth`, "name" is `timeout`, and "value" is the timeout in seconds](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/auth.html#chttpd_auth/timeout).